# How To Display Image to HTML using python

Tags: python, html, image, file, file-upload

*To display image from the path specified to the HTML browser in python. I have coded in this manner.*

index.html

```
<html>
<body>
   <form enctype = "multipart/form-data" 
                     action = "save_file.py" method = "post">
   <p>File: <input type = "file" name = "filename" /></p>
   <p><input type = "submit" value = "Upload" /></p>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**save_file.py**

```
#!C:/Users/Vitriv-Desktop/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/python.exe

import cgi, os
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
from PIL import Image

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

# Get filename here.
fileitem = form['filename']

# Test if the file was uploaded
if fileitem.filename:
   # strip leading path from file name to avoid 
   # directory traversal attacks
   fn = os.path.basename(fileitem.filename)
   open('C:/Apache24/htdocs/tmp/' + fn, 'wb').write(fileitem.file.read())

   message = 'The file "' + fn + '" was uploaded successfully'
   path = 'C:/Apache24/htdocs/tmp/' + fn
   image = Image.open('C:/Apache24/htdocs/tmp/' + fn)
   image.show()
else:
   message = 'No file was uploaded'
   #Content-Type: text/html\n
print ("""\
Content-Type: image/jpg\n
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
   <p>%s </p>
<img src="%s" alt="C:/Apache24/htdocs/tmp/%s">
</body>
</html>
""" % (message,path,fn,))
```

**Expected Output:** It should display image taking from that path specified. 
**Actual Output:** Display with img block with text C:/Apache24/htdocs/tmp/xy.jpg

Comment: are you sure, image is available in the location?

Comment: @Shiva with separate html coded with that path and displayed it into browser to check. It works perfectly

Comment: can you check the path value, and inspect the code

Comment: @Shiva what does it mean?

Comment: Does the file appear on disk at the location you expect? If so, this could be a sort of race condition where your write to the file may be buffered until flushed on close. Regardless, I suggest following the [good practice of using `with` when dealing with file objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Comment: print path variable to cross verify.

Comment: @Galen File has been perfectly written. Thats why I have coded in seperate file giving exact file path stored ie. saved path

Comment: @Shiva Checked It works perfect!

Comment: is it possible to post the screenshot of what you are getting

Comment: @Shiva Is it possible to continue our discussions on chat room after 1 hour break

Comment: ok, sure will talk, invite me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161791/discussion-between-shiva-and-nishanth).

Comment: @Galen 
 Do you know why does the image.show() not working

Answer (score 0):

**Finally the solution lies in the image format not in the file path problem...**

it's for your missing JPEG support in your PIL
here is my solution explained here.
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59718/python-imaging-library-pil-decoder-jpeg-not-available-how-to-fix

Go to [here](http://libjpeg.sourceforge.net/) to download the lib **libjpeg** package.
or just

```
brew install libjpeg
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display image using HTML and its path is specified in python, you can make it easy by using python web framework such as the flask.

```
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Display Picture</label>
  <img id="output" name="img" alt="Display Picture" src="
{{url_for('static',filename=path)}}" />
```

**Note**: Path is variable you can pass it from python.